# GAE: Read static file

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine, static, accessibility

I'm using app engine and I don't know how to read a static file from my project. I have a file structure that globally looks like this:

```
- html (static folder)
   - staticfile1.html
   - staticfile2.html
- script
   - main.py
app.yaml
```

In my app.yaml I already set the application_readably attribute to true for the html dir:

```
- url: /html
  static_dir: html
  application_readable: true
```

I tried several methods to access the staticfile1.html but either of them returns this error:

> [Errno 13] file not accessible: u'/html/staticfile1.html'

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
INDEX_HTML = open('/html'+self.request.path).read()
self.response.out.write(INDEX_HTML)
```

I hope someone knows how I can read the static file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use relative paths based on the current module's `__file__` attribute.  e.g. from `main.py`, you'd do something like:

```
import os
_HERE = os.path.basename(__file__)
_HTML_DIR = os.path.join(_HERE, os.pardir, 'html')
```